# rest api ajax no output in html document

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, rest, api

In a html document I am using this snippet trieing to get a json from a URL.

```
<script type="text/javascript">            
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                document.write(data)
            }
        });
    </script>
```

With document.write(data) I want to display it on my html output in browser. But it only displays "Test". What am I doing wrong here?`

Full html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>ServiceNow Extension</title>
    <script src="sdk/scripts/VSS.SDK.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">VSS.init();</script>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">           
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                document.write(data)
            }
        });
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmmm how are you calling the script of the web service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `document.write`. It clears the whole page. With minimal changes your code works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>ServiceNow Extension</title>
    <script src="sdk/scripts/VSS.SDK.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">VSS.init();</script>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <div id="result"></div><!--Placeholder for the result-->
    <script type="text/javascript">VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                //document.write(data)
                //row response: {id: 76, content: "Hello, World!"}
                //data is already parsed
                $('#result').html(data.content);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Returned data from server is an json object. When you write it it only print some thing like this `[object Object]`. To write some properties of this object write for example as following example:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">            
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                document.write(data.id);
                document.write(data.content);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Or if you want to write object data entirely as string use `JSON.stringify()` function.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">            
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                document.write(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        });
    </script>
```